# Can't handle refreshed token in custom FirebaseInstanceIDService Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When i'm debuging, this part of application doesn't execute, so i don't know when the token is refreshed, Even when i clear data or uninstall application before debug.

This following image presents my code.

[image: Break points]

Please someone can explains this to me ?

Comment: Did you put the service into your manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OKay lets go step by step

First of all in your Activity call this piece of code and make sure your token is generated (Assuming you have done nothing wrong with manifest and other configs like json files etc.)

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

If you get token that means your code is fine but you are unable to debug for some reasons

If this is not working you should go back to google documentation and match your steps

Happy coding!!

Comment: When i call this, `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();` in my Activity, i get the the token. 

But i can't debug in my Custom FirebaseInstanceIdService to know when the token is refreshed.

Comment: un install or clear data from app and then debug  you shall get that, you are not getting because token is not refreshing :)

Token won't refresh unless FCM thinks its security has been compromised

Comment: I have cleared app data, un installed application, when i start application and call `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();` in **MainActivity** the  token is already generated. but still un able to break in FirebaseinstanceIdService

Comment: @ValdèseKamdem if answer of my comments helped you you may accept answer as anyone facing similar issue may find help

Comment: I see your code has already logs written try searching with your tag string in logs you will definitely find events

Comment: i done everything but still having the same state. I log the token in MainActivity and i see it in logs. I also log the new token in `onTokenRefresh()` but didn't see in logs.

After clear data and un install application, the token has changed (i know it because i have handled it in **MainActivity**) but the `onTokenRefresh()` method doesn't execute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127798/discussion-between-valdese-kamdem-and-android-fanatic).

Comment: i saw the problem it was in my **AndroidManifest.xml**

I make a typing's mistake.
    `<action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_Id_EVENT" />`
i suppose to put this : 
    `<action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />`


Big thank for your help